# How to grant access for multiple tables to a user in MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5, mysql-5.5, linux

I have mysql db named "greats"  with four tables as below

```
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_greatstat |
+---------------------+
| log                 |
| sitedet1            |
| siteindex           |
| user                |
| whois1              |
+---------------------+
```

Here i have decided to create an mysql user "test" and i want to give the access only for specific table of the db "greatstat".
So, May i know how to grant specific table perm for an user in MYSQL ?

Answer (score 9):

First create the user

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO test@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'whateverpassword';
```

To grant only SELECT privilege to the siteindex table in the greatstat database

```
GRANT SELECT ON greatstat.siteindex TO test@'localhost';
```

To grant only SELECT privilege to the whois1 table in the greatstat database

```
GRANT SELECT ON greatstat.whois1 TO test@'localhost';
```

To grant all privileges to every table in the greatstat database

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON greatstat.* TO test@'localhost';
```

Please read the [**MySQL Documentation on the GRANT command**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html).

Comment: Thanks for info. You have say to give table privilege by executing multiple query. But , i want to execute in single query.